# Include HostName in ODBC System DSN Connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity, odbc, microsoft-dynamics

Not sure if this is a question for here or if it should go on Stack Overflow. If SO is a better fit, please migrate it.

Our finance team uses Dynamics GP. Occasionally we need to track the query that is being run by a user at a particular computer. I tried to setup an Extended Events session that we could just enable/disable and put in the filter sqlserver.client_hostname:

[image: EE Setup]

I can test it out through SSMS and it works fine, the events are captured. I then tried running Dynamics GP and noticed that no events were captured. Thinking I'd stuffed something up I went back to SQL Profiler and ran a trace and discovered that the HostName is not set:
[image: Profiler]

Dynamics GP connects to SQL via a System ODBC connection.
[image: ODBC]

Is there a way to configure the ODBC connection to send the host name to SQL? I've gone through all of the options and I can't find a tick box that will send it.