# Find source of spids that show no hostname

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, connections

I have a busy SQL 2012 server where connections to one particular database (using the same SQL login) don't show a "hostname", and I need to find out which box (of several) these connections are coming from.

I've tried all the normal built-in and 3rd-party tools (`master.sys.processes`, `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, `sp_who2`, `sp_WhoIsActive`, the SSMS Activity Monitor, even SQL Profiler and Idera Diagnostic Manager), none of them can give me the hostname of the server/client behind these connections, presumably because they all use the same underlying system tables/views.

I'd be fine with an IP address, too, but don't see any way to determine that from within SQL either.

In case this is any help:

- `sys.dm_exec_sessions` shows the `client_interface_name` is ODBC
- Nothing captured for `program_name` either
- The user is a SQL account that happens to be a SYSADMIN (yes, I know...)

I found [a related question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134249/include-hostname-in-odbc-system-dsn-connection) (albeit from the other side), but that went unanswered.

At this point I'm tempted to disable the user so I can capture some failed logins in the SQL errorlog, but I don't imagine the application team will be happy with that.

Comment: It would be a major PITA, and possibly not do-able due to having to install a special driver, but you could use WireShark or Microsoft Network Monitor to track what is connecting to the server via the specified SQL port.

Comment: You don't mention `sys.dm_exec_connections` - I'm sure you've looked there too, but wanted to mention it just in case? Other places to check - default trace (if they do anything that gets logged there) or set up your own trace or extended events session.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep, that was it, see my posted answer.

Comment: Sounds like a shared memory connection which can only originate from the dB server host itself. You can check the `net_transport` column in`dm_exec_connections` to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like I was just asking the question wrong, I found the answer under: [How to get the client IP address from SQL Server 2008 itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941074/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-from-sql-server-2008-itself):

As Aaron mentioned in the comments, I had to use `sys.dm_exec_connections` to get the source IP. Here is the final version of the query I used:

```
SELECT s.session_id, s.login_name, DB_NAME(s.database_id) as database_name, 
    s.host_name, s.program_name, c.client_net_address, client_tcp_port,
    c.net_transport, c.auth_scheme, s.login_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c 
ON s.session_id = c.session_id
WHERE s.login_name = 'MYSTERY_USER'
ORDER BY s.session_id
```